# Constructions getting a value outside of what i put in

Tags: java, loops, class, constructor

For some reason it keeps letting numbers pass 12 in hour. not really sure what is going wrong. I believe it might have something to do with how i have .hour in 2 different steps but when i edit it, it gives me more issues. I end up getting numbers such as 15 for the hour. So far it has not happened with minutes but i believe that has more to do with luck then anything considering both share the same idea.

```
public class Clock {

    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private String period;
    private String timeZone;

    public Clock() {
        this.hour = 12;
        this.minute = 00;
        this.period = "AM";
        this.timeZone = "Eastern";
    }

    public Clock(int hour, int minute, String period, String timeZone) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.period = period;
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }
    
    public boolean setHour(int hour) {
        if (hour >= 1 && hour <= 12) {
            this.hour = hour;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return this.hour;
    }

    public boolean setMinute(int minute) {
        if (minute >= 0 && minute <= 60) {
            this.minute = minute;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return this.minute;
    }

    public boolean setPeriod(String period) {
        if (period.equals("PM") || period.equals("AM")) {
            this.period = period;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return this.period;
    }

    public boolean setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
        if (timeZone.equalsIgnoreCase("Eastern") || timeZone.equalsIgnoreCase("Central") ||
            timeZone.equalsIgnoreCase("Mountain") || timeZone.equalsIgnoreCase("Pacific")) {
            this.timeZone = timeZone;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getTimeZone() {
        return this.timeZone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is setting hour, minute, period, etc. *directly,* instead of calling your setter methods. Therefore, no validation is taking place.

To fix the problem, change your constructor to:

```
public Clock(int hour, int minute, String period, String timeZone) {
    setHour(hour);
    setMinute(minute);
    setPeriod(period);
    setTimeZone(timeZone);
}
```

You should also consider capturing the boolean return values of each of those method calls and throwing an exception if any of them return `false`.